# How can I activate a CSS style for a label when hovering over the associated checkbox?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Every time I hover over the label of a checkbox it turns yellow:

#### Markup

```
<input type="checkbox" value="hello" id="hello" name="deletefiles[]"/>
<label for="hello">hello</label>
```

#### CSS

```
label:hover, label:active {
   background:yellow;
}
```

When I hover over the related checkbox, I want the label to highlight. Is there a way to fire the same hover rule using CSS if I hover over the checkbox as well? Or will I have to use JavaScript for this...?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a CSS sibling selector, like this:

```
label:hover, label:active, input:hover+label, input:active+label {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Note that this won't work in IE6.

Comment: Won't it be nice when IE6 market share is small enough we can stop worrying about what doesn't work in it? It's down to 7.2%. See http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: i stoped supporting ie6 5years ago! :)

Comment: second-question!!! is it possible to highlight the label IF THE CHECKBOX IS CLICKED/SELECTED? that would be interesting!

Comment: You mean if it's checked, but not if it's unchecked?  You can't do that without Javascript

Comment: Handle the `change` event, call `val()`, and add or remove the class as appropiate (`$(this).addClass('...')`)

Comment: @mathiregister: actually, [you could use the :checked pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-25.html) just as you're already using :hover and :active... except that it won't work in any currently-released version of IE...

Answer (score 7):

Just put the checkbox *inside* the label:

```
<label for="hello">
  <input type="checkbox" value="hello" id="hello" name="deletefiles[]"/>
  hello
</label>
```

Now when you hover over the checkbox, you'll also be hovering over the label, and your existing rules will suffice to highlight it.

Comment: @WalterJ89: indeed it is... In fact, you can skip the `for` attribute on the label when the associated input is nested within!

Answer (score 2):

**The jQuery solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hello, label[for="hello"]').hover(function(){$(this).addClass('.hover');},
                                         function(){$(this).removeClass('.hover');});

});

...

.hover
{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

And this DOES work in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*CSS*/
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
input:not(:checked) + label:hover{
  color: #d51e22;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

input:checked + label[for="tab1"],
input:checked + label[for="tab2"],
input:checked + label[for="tab3"],
input:checked + label[for="tab4"]{
 color: #d51e22;
 text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
 background-color: #000;
}

label[for="tab1"],[for="tab2"],[for="tab3"],[for="tab4"] {
  width:24%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size:24px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color: #d51e22;
  color: #fff;
  /*border: 1px solid transparent;*/
}

/*HTML*/
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Text here</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Text here</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Text here</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Text here</label>
```